# HOw to create table with round corners in xsl:fo

Tags: xsl-fo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounded corners in XSL-FO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580147/rounded-corners-in-xsl-fo)

HOw to create table with round corners in xsl:fo

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer may be here on this site [Rounded corners in XSL-FO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580147/rounded-corners-in-xsl-fo)